# Matrix inner product, how can I prove this question

Tags: linear-algebra

$\langle u,v\rangle$ is the Euclidean inner product on $\mathbb R^n$ and $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then

how can I prove $\langle u,Av\rangle = \langle A^Tu,v\rangle$ ?

Comment: Use the definition of the inner product.

Comment: The inner product is $\langle u,v \rangle:=u^t v$. Use its symmetry to deduce the rest.

Comment: It is sufficient to check for $u,v \in \{b_1,...,b_n\}$ where the latter is a basis. Choose a convenient basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the definition of inner product $⟨u,v⟩:=u^Tv$. Then

$$⟨u,Av⟩=u^T(A^T)^Tv=(A^Tu)^Tv=⟨A^Tu,v⟩$$